# Which engine has the highest nozzle wall temperature?

Tags: engines, temperature, nozzle

From all the rocket engines that were used in flight, which one has the highest nozzle wall temperature?

The nozzle wall is not heated uniformly. But there are regions where they reach max temperature.  I am interested in both solid and liquid engines, but only in the nozzle wall temperature, not the chamber temperature.

Which engine nozzles have the highest such peak temperature?

Comment: What is the "nozzle temperature"? As you can see in this answer, the temperature of the gas and the wall vary with distance down the nozzle.https://space.stackexchange.com/a/48186/6944

Comment: The temperature of the inside wall of the nozzle. Where the gas touches nozzle

Comment: That still includes the full length of the nozzle

Comment: "Needs details or clarity"

Comment: Full length yes. Along that lenght some points reach a max temperature that I was asking for

Comment: Maybe you should  ask about chamber temperature.

Comment: Why to ask about chamber if I am curious about the max temperature a nozzle wall can get?

Comment: Your question is similar to: "what is the hottest chimney?" depending on how you define the chimney it will obviously be the point closest to the fire burning in the hearth, which is why you need to either be more specific or you'll get the same answer as asking "what engine has the highest chamber temperature"

Comment: Also some important things to consider: do you mean engines flown or also engines tested? Only liquid propellant engines or also solid rocket boosters? If you include tested it is probably one of the Rocketdyne or Energomash tripropellant test engines and if you don't focus on liquid engines only I guess its a O2/HTPB solid booster, maybe the Atlas V boosters, the GEM63 or its bigger brother the GEM63XL

Comment: Both liquid and solid

Comment: @JoeJobs you should edit your question to include precision you added in comment (engine considered, which temperature you are speaking of,...)

Comment: I really have no idea how to ddo it. Can you do it for me please?